# PLP - Display an image with role

Tags: product-images

I am trying to show another image on the product listing page, I have located the code at: **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml**

On the product image section in admin I have selected another image and applied a custom role i.e. (Plp Hover)

How can I display this image in the file above? I've tried the below with no luck

```
<?php echo $block->getImageUrl('plp_hover'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getMediaGalleryImages('plp_hover') ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In which file did you tried this code?

Comment: In this one: Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml

Comment: Not sure. But, try to use this code : $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('plp_hover')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());

Comment: check it. and tell me did you get image name?

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately it gives this error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null

Comment: Please check it you get product id or not. $block->getProduct()->getId();

Comment: hmm same error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null